# Compiler of c type equivalence

Tags: c

In C language, if we have:

```
typedef int a[100];
typedef int b[200];
```

Then types a and b are equivalent?
As far as I know C uses name equivalence,
but I'm very confused.

Comment: Try `sizeof` on each one of them...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why? *Same size* doesn't necessarily mean *same type*. `typeof()` (where supported) would be a better idea.

Comment: @tofro *Different* size is *necessarily* meaning different type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example `a` is alias for the type `int[100]` and `b` is an alias for the type `int[200]`. These two types are not equivalent as an array's size is part of its type and different sizes mean different types.

If the second line were `typedef int b[100];`, `a` and `b` would be equivalent.

> As far as i know C uses name equivalence

Structs and unions are nominally typed in the sense that if you have two struct (or union) types tagged A and B, which have exactly the same body, they're still considered different types. So if a variable has type `struct A`, you can't assign it a `struct B` without converting it first.

This is not true for `typedef`s, which are mere aliases. So if you have two typedefs `typedef X a; typedef X b;`, then `X`, `a` and `b` are all indistinguishable from each other.